# Simple program expected identifier before '(' token

Tags: c++

this is the first time that i ask but i need help because its a simple program and i dont know how to fix this problem
(please excuse my english, im from bolivia and i am also bad)

```
int ini;
int fin;
int tam;
int f;
f=2;
int papu;
cout<<"Ingresa el inicio y el final de tus elementos"<<endl;
cout<<"Desde: ";
cin>>ini;
cout<<"Hasta: ";
cin>>fin;
cout<<endl;
tam=((fin+1)-ini);
cout<<"Tu vector tiene "<<tam<<" elementos"<<endl;
int numeros[tam];
cout<<"Los numeros primos dentro de tu vector son: "<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<tam;i++) {
numeros[i]=papu;
    if (papu%papu==0) && ((papu%f)!=0) {
    cout << "El numero "<<papu<<" es primo" << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: It's much easier for us to help if the post is in English. As with the answers, you're missing parenthesis around your `if` statement expressions. Though you're also reading an uninitialised variable `papu` and even if it were initialised `papu%papu==0` would be a superfluous check as a natural number divided by the same natural number will never have a remainder, the if can be reduced to `if( papu%f != 0 )` or even `if( papu%f )`. Also `int numeros[tam];` is not valid C++, and therefore not portable. etc...

Answer (score 1):

your "if" statement `if (papu%papu==0) && ((papu%f)!=0)` is missing parentheses around the whole thing. It should be `if ((papu%papu==0) && ((papu%f)!=0))`

Comment: @EduardoBrito if this is the answer you were looking for, [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis:

```
if ((papu%papu==0) && ((papu%f)!=0) {
cout << "El numero "<<papu<<" es primo" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The if conditions must be between ()

```
if ((papu%papu==0) && (papu%f!=0))
```